# Python Apache beam streaming to Bigquery is getting failed

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to write Apache beam output to Bigquery Table but its getting failed with InsertError as below.Please help.

## Code:

```
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from mongodbio import ReadFromMongo

TABLE_SCHEMA = ('clause_type:STRING, count:INTEGER')

def transform_doc(document):
    data={str(document['clause_type']):int(document['count'])}
    return data


def run():
    connection_string = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as pipeline:
        (pipeline
        | 'read' >> ReadFromMongo(connection_string, 'new', 'Data', 
          query={}, fields=['count','clause_type'])
        | 'transform' >> 
          beam.Map(transform_doc).with_output_types(str)
        | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('<table_name>',schema=TABLE_SCHEMA,create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    run()
```

## Error:

```
  index: <index number>>, <InsertErrorsValueListEntry
  errors: [<ErrorProto
  debugInfo: u'generic::not_found: no such field.'
  location: u'fiscal year'
  message: u'no such field.'
  reason: u'invalid'>]
```

Comment: Where did the field "fiscal year" come from?

Comment: No idea as such field is neither present in my DB data nor in my BQ table.

Comment: Well, I think we need to solve that mystery first. `fiscal year` is not on your DB data, nor your table, nor your code... but it shows up in the error logs.

Comment: The issue got resolved after putting timestamp in TABLE_SCHEMA as BQ insertion require that.